# Paypal accounts cannot ship purchases

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express

We're having this trouble when we try to test the paypal express checkout, our merchant country is United Arab Emirates

[image: Paypal Error]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message tells you everything:

> PayPal Philippines accounts cannot ship purchases to United Arab Emirates

For some reasons, you're using a PayPal Philippines account on your UAE store. I suggest you create an UAE PayPal account to use for this store. This is the official UAE website for PayPal: https://www.paypal.com/ae/webapps/mpp/home

Comment: is there no work around on this? so people from philippines cannot buy from our store?

Comment: @Margz that's a PayPal restriction I suggest you contact PayPal directly. I reckon you can't avoid that as some stolen credit cards payment come from Philippines.